# JS Variable Can Be Seen In Chrome Console, But Isn't Explicitly Defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

Noob Question of the day:

I have created a web page with an HTML element that has an ID. This web page uses jquery and a handful of other libraries.

ex) `<div id="personList ">`

In the .js used by the page I manipulate the element using jquery and it's #id as the selector - works like a charm.

ex) `$("#personList")...`

In the Chrome console simply typing in `personList` displays the HTML element and its attributes. I would have assumed it would not - as there's no javascript variable created with that name...

Is this because:

1. Chrome is smart enough to recognize the element in the DOM and
   assumes I was referring to it?
2. Something automagically created a variable out of the element and
   put it into the global (or other near-global) scope ?
3. Something else entirely?

I am sure this has been answered somewhere, and is likely well documented, but I'm at a loss when trying to find it with my keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM element IDs are global variables.

From the HTML5 [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

> the value of the id content attribute for all HTML elements that have
>   a non-empty id content attribute and are in a document tree with
>   window's browsing context's active document as their root.

So if we have: `<div id="bar"></div>`, you can access that element through: `window.bar`

```js
console.log(window.test);
window.test.innerHTML = 'amazing';
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Relying on this this "feature" can be the cause of a lot of bugs, so I recommend to **never** use it. Take the following example:

```js
window.that.innerHTML = 'It works';

// some library declares `that` as a global variable
window.that = {};

// This won't work, since window.that no longer references the DOM element
window.that.innerHTML = 'It no longer works';
```

```html
<div id="that">Evil div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to reasons best lost in history, elements with an `ID` element become attached to the `global` object and acts like global variables.

They can be shadowed by declaring a variable (with `let`, `const` or `var`) globally.

When you type `personList` in the console, it access `window.personList`.

This is not a behavior that should be relied on anymore but remains to keep backwards compatibility with some ancient code.

Comment: `Due to reasons best lost in history` - very well said.